# Can "old" ASP.Net SignalR be used in ASP.Net Core 3.x app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

You might ask why I would want to use old SignalR in ASP.Net Core.  Well, I have an old MVC 4 app that I cannot completely rewrite and want to use it in conjunction with a new ASP.Net Core 3.1 app with the 2 apps potentially communicating via Web API and SignalR.  Since ASP.Net SignalR is not compatible with Asp.Net Core SignalR I would need to run ASP.Net SignalR in my ASP.Net Core app.  If this is not possible, then I certainly could not write the new app in ASP.Net and not ASP.Net Core.  Just trying to understand possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

After a little further work, I don't believe that this is possible